# Facebook Open Graph Debugger response code 0

Tags: facebook-opengraph, cloudflare

I have problems with my domain and Facebook Open Graph Debugger. It [returns](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=eldoradoexperience.org%2Fchapter%2Fcosmos) a Response Code 0 for this [link](http://eldoradoexperience.org/chapter/cosmos) which is completely accesible.

My HTML source code is valid, I tried hosting the same page in another domain and then Facebook Open Graph Debugger can read the content fine.

Any ideas about this problem? I was using CloudFlare in this domain, but I disabled it 30 hours ago and the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll down to the bottom of the page and click the "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" you'll get an empty page.  This suggest that yes, the Facebook **scraper** is not able to view your page for some reason as you've observed.  This is the heart of the problem, and you can safely ignore the other erroneous and inaccurate messages that Facebook debugger displays, including:

- Inferred Property The 'og:image' property should be explicitly
  provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
- Inferred
  Property The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if
  a value can be inferred from other tags.
- Inferred Property The
  'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value
  can be inferred from other tags.
- Share App ID Missing The 'fb:app_id'
  property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that
  stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app.
  Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.

After looking at your code, it seems that all of your Facebook meta tags are being set correctly.

If you view the link "Open Graph Object Debugger" at the bottom of the page, you will get much more helpful information:

```
The following will be treated as a redirect by the crawler:
A HTTP redirect
A <link rel="canonical" href=".." /> tag
A <meta property="og:url" content=".." /> tag
The final URL, which we tried to extract metadata from is highlighted in bold
```

I'm guessing that the Facebook bot is getting confused by one or the other of the following tags being added by the Yoast SEO plugin:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noodp"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://eldoradoexperience.org/chapter/cosmos/" />
```

I'm not familiar with Yoast SEO plugin, but would suggest either tweaking the settings to remove the `<link rel="...">` tag or by removing Yoast entirely and adding the following tags to your page manually:

```html
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Cosmos. Reading the celestial ceiling" />
<meta property="og:description" content="I decided to switch off all GPS electronic devices. I step on the deck and look at my surroundings, in order to understand the workings of the stars." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://eldoradoexperience.org/chapter/cosmos/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Eldorado experience" />
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/NarinanVessel" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://eldoradoexperience.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/dorado-33_2.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Finally, I deduced that this was caused by a Facebook Opengraph Debugger bug. Trying to scrap information with the old version of the debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object) worked fine and solved the problem, which doesn't make a lot of sense...