# Facebook API scraper site, facebook debugger, error response

Tags: javascript, facebook, meta, sharing

I have a website sharing problem,

I use those tags, but have problem with scraping on facebook debugger

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1173142976079604"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="https://oplao.com/"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="OPLAO - Профессиональный Прогноз Погоды по Всему Миру"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="В Львове погода сейчас: температура, влажность, ветер, облачность, вероятность осадков, атмосферное давление, видимость на дорогах."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://oplao.com/images/share.jpg"/>
```

Url to facebook debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Foplao.com%2F

Url to my site oplao.com

Please scrape and see, the response code is 301((

On the screen there are failed information, please see:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1jW8.png)

Comment: Then debug your servers logs why you return response code 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Open Graph Debugger response code 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729090/facebook-open-graph-debugger-response-code-0)

Comment: No, I had old site on another server with this domain name, old version of site, after updating we changed ip, so now ip is right, but meta data are wrong

Comment: I debug my server it is good, there are no problems, it returns nice response

Comment: No it is not good. It returns strange result to Facebook.

Comment: Use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/, that usually is a more descriptive in its error messages. Says it detected a circular redirect path, so look into that.

Comment: So I tried those things((

Comment: Now it shows 301 error